# How to plot horizontal lines in scatter plot in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to plot a time series with two horizontal lines (depicting limits in my case).

How do I do this?

Example of what I'm trying to achieve (horizontal lines drawn in Paint):

[image: horizontal lines in Excel]

Comment: an easy way to do that is to define two more data: [min(x) max(x)] and [2 2], and plot this. since the [2 2] does not change, it produces an horizontal line. You can then change the x-limits of the plot, so the horizontal line cross the entire plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know of to do this, the first is essentially as advised by @Thales, just including more detail.

**FIRST APPROACH**

- Include 2 new columns I labelled these UCL and LCL for upper control
  limit and lower control limit respectively.
- Shade all 4 columns and select Insert > Charts (select Scatter Chart)
  as shown in the figure below:

[image: Add data to scatter chart from the worksheet]

- Re-position the graph, then Right click on each horizontal series and
  format the data series change the color and set the marker to 'None'.

[image: Trend chart the first approach]

**THE SECOND WAY (My Personal Preference)...**

If you do not want to add the columns you can do the following:

- Once you have your base chart without the horizontal lines, right
  click the chart and click 'Select Data...'

[image: Add data to a trend chart]

- Under 'Legend Entries (Series)' select the 'Add' button
- Name the series
- enter ={1,20} in the Series X values field - this is the start and end values for the x range
- enter ={4,4} in the Series Y values field - these are the corresponding Y values see below

[image: Scatter chart with direct data entry]

- Repeat for the other horizontal line using values ={1,20} for the X Series and ={2,2} for the Y Series.
- Next format the lines as described above and there you have it a
  chart without the need to add another series.

[image: Trend chart second approach]

Comment: I prefer the first method, because if I need to adjust the positions of the lines, all I need to do is edit a few cells. Using the second method, I need to go through that most-hated Select Data dialog, change values, and make sure I don't mess up the leading equals sign and the curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

There's a **Third Way** and I believe is the best way to do this.

Use the same method as described in the **Second Way**, except do as shown in the image below:

[Example of adding Upper and Lower limits using cell references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRH3C.png)

Comment: Answers must contain all necessary information in themselves. Links are OK for extra study and are expected for attribution, but they are not sufficient as answers.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.